# 2 copies of 1 project,how i can generate 2 different SHA-1

Tags: android, firebase, package, sha1

I have the 1 project(Taxi app), both driver and customer sides are in same app, but demand these two separate apps, i just copy same project and change login screens and also change some more package name etc

but SHA-1 is same
What is the possible solution of it? i want to add these two apps on firebase in same project

Comment: ISSUE RESOLVED

I just changed my package name 
com.abc.abcuser
com.abc.abcdriver

i think issue was that my package name was less different from other only different in last of my package (user & driver)
I just make it more different and with same SHA-1 firebase accept my app

com.abc.user
com.abc.driver

issue resolved

Answer (score 0):

firebase accepts the same SHA-1 key if they are in the same project. we are creating 30 apps in one firebase project.